# About totally isotropic subspace

Tags: linear-algebra, bilinear-form

This is [Definition 1.4.1](https://books.google.com/books?id=c27pCAAAQBAJ&pg=PA12) and [Lemma 1.4.2](https://books.google.com/books?id=c27pCAAAQBAJ&pg=PA12) from the book W._Scharlau: *Quadratic and Hermitian forms.*

> **4.1. Definition.** A vector $x\ne 0$ in a bilinear space $(V,b)$ is called *isotropic* if $b(x,x) = 0$. Otherwise $x$ is called *anisotropic*. 
>   If $(V,b)$ contains an isotropic vector, then $(V,b)$ is called *isotropic* as well. We will also say that $(V,b)$ represents zero. 
>   Otherwise $(V,b)$ is called anisotropic. A subspace $W$ of $V$ is called totally isotropic if $b(W, W)=0$, that is $b(x,y)=0$ for all $x,y\in W$.
>
> Let $V$ be a vector space and $V^*$ its dual space. 
>   On the vector space $V\oplus V^*$ we consider the following symmetric bilinear form
>   \begin{gather*}
> h=h_V\colon (V\oplus V^*)\times (V\oplus V^*) \to K\\
> h((x,f),(y,g))=fy+gx
> \end{gather*}
>   (One can easily check that $h$ is a symmetric bilinear form.)
>
> **4.2. Lemma.** (i) $(V\oplus V^*,h_V)$ is regular.
>   (ii) $V$ and $V^*$ are totally isotropic subspaces.

[image]

[image]

I found bit confusing how to show $V$ and it's dual is totally isotropic for that I need to show $h(x,y)=0$ for all $x$, $y$ in $V$ and it's dual. Where $h$ is given bilinear symmetric form

Comment: I have tried to retype some stuff from your picture. It is recommended (when possible) that the question should be readable without pictures. Aside from that, it is also useful (for readers of your question and for potential answerers) to include also source of the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to check that
$$h((x,0),(y,0))=0 \qquad\text{and}\qquad h((0,f),(0,g))=0$$
for any $x,y\in V$ and $f,g\in V^*$.

The first equation shows that $V$ is a totally isotopic subspace of $V\oplus V^*$. The second equation shows that this is true for $V^*$. (Notice that we identify $V$ with $V\times\{0\}$ and $V^*$ with $\{0\}\times V^*$.)

I will remind you (look at the Definition 4.1) that to show that something is a totally isotropic subspace you only need $b(x,y)$ for $x$ and $y$ *from this subspace.* In this case you are applying this to the bilinear for $h$ and to the subspaces $V$ and $V^*$.